# jQuery change position when element reaches top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I'm trying to change the CSS position of an element of my page, basically is just a sidebar widget that I want to change the position from absolute to fixed once the element reaches the top of the page. An example can be seen here on stackoverflow when you ask a question they have a side bar that stays in one position until it reaches the top of the page. So basically I wondering how can I test the position of an element with jQuery, thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .offset() and scrollTop() to find the distance between an element and the top of the viewable area.

```
var distanceFromTop = $("testSelector").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
```